# clicking anywhere on form checking/unchecking checkbox

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, icheck

This is a vague question so i didn't want to ask but after spending couple of hours, i got no clue and want to depend on SO expertise people.

so basically in my website http://admire-laravel6.lorvent.in/generator_builder

if i click on "add field" then try to click on any input field of new row like field name,
it only checks/unchecks last checkbox.

issue seems be because of icheck, which creates an `ins` tag which has width of 100%.

but when i try to origin bootstrap 4, this issue doesn't exists.

really not sure, what is causing it.

any advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the icheck and the reason is **because the 100% is in absolute position but there's no relative parent** to control where it needs to be:

Try adding:

```
.icheckbox_square-blue {
    position: relative;
}
```

You will see then it will start working the way you want it.